# Uniform approximation over compacts using weighted function spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, compactness

I'm interested in approximations over the so-called **weighted function spaces**.

Let $(X,\tau_X)$ be some completely regular Hausdorff topological space. Additionally, consider some map $\psi: X \to (0,\infty)$ such that, for all $R>0$, $\psi^{-1}((0,R])$ is compact with respect to $\tau_X$. The map $\psi$ is said to be **admissible**. The tuple $(X,\psi)$ is said to be a **weighted space**.

Typical examples of weighted spaces are normed spaces $X$ endowed with a weaker topology that makes $\psi(x) := \eta(||x||_X)$ admissible, where $\eta: [0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ is some continuous and increasing function. For instance, think of dual spaces equipped with the weak-$*$-topology and apply the Banach-Alaoglu theorem.

Equipped with a weighted space, one can define a **weighted function space**. Specifically, consider the following vector space
$$F_\psi(X):= \left\{ f:X \to \mathbb{R} : \sup_{x\in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{\psi(x)} <\infty \right\},$$
which can be seen as the space of real-valued maps over $X$ whose growth is controlled by $\psi: X \to (0,\infty)$. We equip $F_\psi(X)$ with the norm $||\cdot||_{\psi}$ given by
$$||f||_{\psi} = \sup_{x\in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{\psi(x)}.$$
Lastly, by observing that the set of real-valued bounded continuous functions over $X$, denoted by $C_b^0(X)$, is continuously embedded in $F_\psi(X)$, we define the **weighted function space** $\mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ as the $||\cdot||_{\psi}$-closure of $C_b^0(X)$.

My question is the following:

Let us assume that we have a weighted space $(X,\psi)$, where $X$ is normed and $\psi= \eta(||x||_X)$ is admissible for some continuous increasing function $\eta: [0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$. Furthermore, assume there's a subset  $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ that's dense in $\mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ wrt $||\cdot||_\psi$, i.e. for all $f \in \mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ and $\epsilon >0$, there exists $(f_n) \subset \mathcal{A}$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in X} \frac{|f(x) - f_n(x)|}{\psi(x)} \leq \epsilon.$$
**What are some sufficient conditions to have uniform approximations over compacts?** Precisely, if $K \subset X$ is a compact wrt the topology $\tau_X$, I'd like to have
$$\sup_{x\in K} |f(x) - f_n(x)| \leq \epsilon,$$
thus removing $\psi$ from the estimate. For instance, if $X$ is a finite dimensional Banach space, then $\tau_X$ can be the usual norm-induced topology and by Heine-Boreal $\psi = \eta(||x||_X)$ is admissible. Moreover, $\psi$ is continuous, thus uniform approximations are easily obtained using the extreme value theorem if one has a subset $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ that's dense in $\mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ wrt $||\cdot||_\psi$. That said, $X$ being finite dimensional is rather uninteresting... Any suggestions for other sufficient conditions?

**-------------------- **Edit** --------------------**

Note that the admissible map $\psi$ is usually not continuous. Even if $\psi$ is of the form $\eta(||\cdot||_X)$, the norm $||\cdot||_X$ is usually not continuous considering that $X$ is endowed with a rather coarse topology.

**------------------- **Edit 2** -------------------**

I reckon that the goal should be finding conditions such that the topology in $\mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ induced by $||\cdot||_{\psi}$ is stronger than the topology of compact convergence (topology of uniform convergence on compact sets). Something akin to the so-called strict topology.

Comment: Being a continuous real-valued function, $\psi$ has an upper bound $M$ on the compact set $K$. One thus gets $$\sup_{x\in K} |f(x)| \le \sup_{x\in K} \frac{|f(x)|}{\psi(x)} M = M\|f\|_\psi.$$ This is so simple that I'm afraid of missing something...

Comment: That's what I wrote "$\psi$ is continuous, thus uniform approximations are easily obtained using the extreme value theorem".

Comment: @JochenWengenroth the problem is that $\psi$ is usually not continuous, due to $X$ having a weaker topology that doesn't make $||\cdot||_X$ continuous.

Comment: It is not clear to me for what exactly you ask sufficient conditions on the $\|\cdot\|_\psi$-dense set $\mathcal A$. Do you want:  (A) for all $f\in\mathcal B_\psi(X)$, every sequence $(f_n)_n\subset \mathcal A$ converging to $f$ in the norm $\|\cdot\|_\psi$, also converges to uniformly on compact sets.  Or do you want:  (B) for all $f\in\mathcal B_\psi(X)$, there exists a sequence $(f_n)_n\subset \mathcal A$ converging to $f$ in the norm $\|\cdot\|_\psi$ and uniformly on compact sets.

Comment: Or do you want:  (C) for all $f\in\mathcal B_\psi(X)$, there exists a sequence $(f_n)_n\subset \mathcal A$ converging to $f$ in the norm $\|\cdot\|_\psi$, and a sequence $(g_n)_n\subset \mathcal A$ converging to $f$ uniformly on compact sets.

Comment: @PietroMajer thanks for the reply. Assuming that for any function $f\in \mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ we have a sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathcal{A}$ such that $||f-f_n||_\psi \to 0$, i.e. $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ wrt $||\cdot||_\psi$, when can we say that for the same approximating sequence $(f_n)$ we have a uniform approximation on any compact $K$, i.e. for any $\epsilon >0$, $\sup_{x\in K} |f(x) - f_n(x)| \leq \epsilon$. I reckon that the conditions can be imposed on the initial topological space $X$.

Comment: Like in my trivial example, by assuming that $X$ is a finite Banach space. Then, uniform approximation on compact follows by the reasoning expressed by @JochenWengenroth